# Accessing both parent object, and calling object, in callback?

Tags: javascript, object, this, coffeescript

I have a library-provided function that runs a callback after some processing.

Inside that callback, I'd like to access the parent object whose method starts that callback - see below.

```
class MaskMaker
  addMaskedImage: (imagefile, texturefile, canvasid) ->
    $('<img src="'+imagefile+'">').load ->
      console.log('Id like to call another MaskMaker method with @width as a parameter')
```

Obviously => will give me access to the parent object as this/@, -> will give me access to the element triggering the callback as this/@. But what's the neatest way to do both, eg, so I could call a direct method of MaskMaker with the images width as a parameter? Do I need a that = this hack or is there something better?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But what's the neatest way to do both, eg, so I could call a direct method of MaskMaker with the images width as a parameter?

You can't choose both (obviously), so would have to go with either `=>` + `event.target`

```
$('<img src="'+imagefile+'">').load (ev) => @method ev.target.width
```

or good ol'

```
that = this
$('<img src="'+imagefile+'">').load -> that.method @width
```

See also: https://github.com/jashkenas/coffee-script/issues/1230

Comment: The first solution is exactly what I was looking for - no need for 'that' or 'self' hacks. The JQuery docs mention you can pass the object explicitly - http://api.jquery.com/load-event - but I missed this. Thanks muchly.

Answer (score 2):

If I'm understanding your structure of code completely, you can add a variable that holds a reference to the instance of MaskMaker. Due to scope, you'll be able to see anything further down the chain.

```
class MaskMaker
  var self = this;
  addMaskedImage: (imagefile, texturefile, canvasid) ->
    $('<img src="'+imagefile+'">').load ->
      console.log('Id like to call another MaskMaker method with @width as a parameter')
      //self references MaskMaker now, so you can call self.addMaskedImage for example
```

Comment: That works fine (replacing 'var self = this;' with 'self = @'. I was wondering (and I've since edited the question to say) is there anything built into the coffeescript that could avoid having to do this kind of stuff. But I suspect not: you could be many functions deep beneath the object you'd like to reference and JS/CS has no way of knowing which one in particular you'd like to call.

Comment: I'm not in a position to say if Coffeescript does, but Javascript does not.

Answer (score 0):

Define and bind your callback within the scope of MaskMaker:

```
 class MaskMaker
     afterAdd => console.log('Id like to call another MaskMaker method with @width as a parameter')
     addMaskedImage: (imagefile, texturefile, canvasid) ->
         $('<img src="'+imagefile+'">').load -> afterAdd()
```

Note that I'm using the fat arrow syntax `=>` to bind the function stored in afterAdd to MaskMaker.

Comment: This doesn't work.  First, you meant `afterAdd = => ...`.  More importantly, however, `afterAdd` is bound to the `MaskMaker` constructor, not to the instance.

Comment: NM, you're binding to the constructor on purpose. My mistake.